# MSC000001: Failed to start service org.wildfly.undertow.listener.default:Address already in use /127.0.0.1:8081

Tags: postgresql, keycloak, h2

ERROR:

MSC000001: Failed to start service org.wildfly.undertow.listener.default: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service org.wildfly.undertow.listener.default: Address already in use /127.0.0.1:8081

When I started the keycloak, faced this issue.

If anyone comes across the same kind of issue, it's best to provide some suggestions.

Comment: Please note that "provide suggestions" is not a question ([ask]).  But also: I think "Address already in use /127.0.0.1:8081" is quite a good error message or search term. What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a lot of time, I finally found the resolution:

Step-1: first verify the `/etc/hosts` file for invalid mappings.
In my case, the below invalid mappings are there.

```
127.0.0.1  localhost
::1   localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
fe00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
fe00::1 ip6-allnodes
fe00::2 ip6-allrouters
10.32.12.25    keycloak-f744f7965-lg7hj
```

I tried to remove this last line from the hosts file, but it is not allowed due to permission.

I finally restarted the same pod and then it got resolved.